# Laravel :value in another language

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 8
php 7.1

I have a form with some input fields. The form is available in English and German. 
If you don't enter something in the German version and want to send it, the following text appears:

```
Dieses Feld wird benötigt wenn job description nicht vorhanden ist.
```

(In English that means `This field is required if the job description is not available.` )

How can I replace the `job description` (`:values`) with a German word.

Here is my `resources/lang/de/validation.php` file:

```
'required_without'     => 'Dieses Feld wird benötigt wenn :values nicht vorhanden ist.',
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-attribute-in-language-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: in your /de folder

```
 'values' => [
    'job_description' => 'Job Beschreibung'
    ],
```